# Sorting Objects C# with IComparable

Tags: c#, compareto, icomparable

I'm trying to find what I'm doing wrong in the following code in order to sort list of specific object items.

The object is network group - which has a UID (some id) and list of members (represented as list of all the members UID's)

**(Loops are not valid - A can not consist B when B consist A)**

For example:

Group1 - UID: 1   Members UID's: 2, 3.

Group2 - UID: 4   Members UID's: 6.

Group3 - UID: 5   Members UID's: 7.

Group4 - UID: 2   Members UID's: 4.

Group5 - UID: 3   Members UID's: 5.

(UID's 7 and 4 are not groups)

This is also the order of the creation of the objects and adding them to the list of the network groups.

This is how I implemented 'compareTo' where the object implements IComparable -

```
    public int CompareTo(NetworkObjectGroup other)
    {
        if(this.MembersByUid.Contains(other.UID))
        {
            return 1; 
        }

        else if (other.MembersByUid.Contains(this.UID))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I'm using the following call in order to sort the list -

```
this.MainWindow.DbObject.NetworkObjectGroups.Sort();
```

At the end of the call the list is not sorted and stay the same...
What am I doing wrong?

After sorting i'm adding the output to a data table and show in a WPF app UI,
each row represents one of the objects, this is the result - 
[image: result]

I want it to be sorted by dependencies for example:

Group2

Group3

Group4

Group5

Group1

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Your comparison isn't transitive... Not all elements can be compared between them. If A is parent, B is child of A and C is child of B, with your comparison it isn't possible to compare A with C, but only A with B and B with C.

Comment: You are checking if the UID of one *group* is in the list of *members* of the other group. Since a group can not be a member in your example, the result of every comparison is 0. That explains your result.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can run and see your code in action.

Comment: Thanks! I undetstood now the issue.. another idea how to implement in with CompareTo ? or I'll think about some other way to do the sort

Comment: @OrelHasis Don't do it with a Compare. You have a tree. Copy all the elements in a `Dictionary<int, NetworkObjectGroup>`, then do manually the sort. You have a tree, remember!

Comment: "some other way to do the sort" - which sort?  Your problem is the definition, not the implementation. When A is a member of B and vice versa, which one is greater?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aVy0e9

Comment: @bommelding  - It's not a valid case that can happen. there are no loops.

Comment: You didn't say that before. [edit] the question.